# Program hangs for no reason

Tags: c#, debugging, c#-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I am using tpl for executing data in parallel. The problem is that sometimes it hangs for no reason giving such an output:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x4aa4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2bf4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x417c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x432c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3ad0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x4440) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x24e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3354) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x4a30) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The program would still be executing and when i pause it in visual studio it pauses where i have the parallel procedure for the ForEach:

```
Parallel.ForEach
(
   hold1.remainingHolds.ToArray(), 
   subSequence =>
   {
      //only if subsequence has 1 common substring
      if (checkIfCommon(remainingSequence, subSequence.ToString()) == 1)
      {
         goDownLinkType2(subSequence.ToString().Split(','), 0, 
           (SuffixNode)hold1.childHolds[subSequence.ToString().Split(',')[0]]);
       }
    }
  );
```

I dont think its a dead lock cause there is no case where there can be a thread waiting for different resources and evetually locking each other

it should enter inside this method and recursivley go dow a suffix tree untill it would wait till no thread is adding any object to the arraylist

```
 Boolean flag = false;
 public void goDownLinkType2
      (string[] splittedString, 
       int index, SuffixNode currentNode)
       {
          Boolean writingFlag = false;
          if (index == 2)
          {
             while(writingFlag == false)
             {
                while(flag == true)
                {
        //blocked
                 }
                 if (flag == false)
                 {
                    flag = true;
                 if(!secondChoiceResults.Contains
                     (currentNode.representingStance.SequenceOfHolds))
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine("new addition");
                    secondChoiceResults.Add
                       (currentNode.representingStance.SequenceOfHolds,
                        currentNode.representingStance);
                  }
                  flag = false;
                  writingFlag = true;
               }
            }

         }
         else
         {
            int nextIndex = index + 1;
            goDownLinkType2
              (splittedString, 
               nextIndex,
               (SuffixNode)currentNode.childHolds[splittedString[nextIndex]]
              );
          }
       }
```

Comment: Does the `Parallel.ForEach` eventually terminate?  If it does, this is by-design.  It's terminating all of the threads in the thread pool that were spun up to satisfy your request.  If it doesn't terminate, is there some boundary condition that is holding one or more of the threads open?

Comment: In the program it is supposed to terminate but in this case it should not at that stage as not all data would have been processed. Also afterwards it is supposed to reach a breakpoint which is never reached and the program just hangs at the foreach.

Comment: Is it possible that you're interpreting the output as termination of processing, when in fact it could just be that the `Parallel.ForEach` simply no longer needs those threads, and is therefore releasing them to the ThreadPool?  If you want a more specific answer, you will need to tell us a little more about your breakpoint: where it is, what code is there, and why you expect it to be hit.

Comment: the if so it might be a problem that 1 thread is getting stuck inside the foreach? as all the other threads are ready from their processing and 1 got stuck.

Comment: My understanding of `Parallel.ForEach` is that control is not returned to the caller until all threads have exited.  You might try executing your actions synchronously instead of asynchronously so that you have more visibility into the one that is hanging up.

Comment: Pass in ParallelOptions object with MaxDegreeOfParallelism set to 1 and see if it still hangs...

Comment: @RobertHarvey added more code and usless to show the breakpoit as it is outside this scope as when it is supposed to terminate it would go back to the outter scope and proceed with the flow of the program i included where it supposed to go i.e. getDownLinkType2

Comment: It's very common for `The thread '<No Name>' (0xXXXX) has exited with code 0 (0x0)` to be displayed at (seemingly) random.  Why do you think that has anything to do with your `ForEach`?

Comment: @PeterRitchie as when i pause the program the debugger highlights the Parallel.ForEach in green.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: That many at once?  It's almost certainly coming from the ForEach.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why not, that's displayed by Windows (even in native applications) for any thread that exits in your application memory space.  You don't know what .NET is doing under the covers; those might be completely legitimate thread terminations (GC, TPL, async IO, etc...)

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use Parallel.ForEach with *any* shared data (like `flag`, `remainingSequence`).  That shared data is read by multiple threads and should either be guarded or accessed via a violate access...

Comment: @Moho in a single thread it doesnt get stuck and executes till termination

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes indeed thats the whole point of the the flag, such that i am blocking access to the critical section and only limit to one thread at a time the access to adding an item to the arraylist and remaining sequence is just read by multiple threads not edit, multiple readers does not do any damage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toss the 'flag' variable and use a lock statement.  It is possible for more than one thread to be in your critical section with this code (i.e. one thread is about to set flag = true while another thread just evaluated flag == false as true (btw just use !flag in the future)

```
lock( obj )
{
    // critical section here
}
```

obj just needs to be a reference to an object accessible to all threads.

Here's my modifications to your code:

```
public void goDownLinkType2(string[] splittedString, int index, SuffixNode currentNode)
{
    Boolean writingFlag = false;
    if (index == 2)
    {
        while(writingFlag == false)
        {
            lock( this )
            //while(flag == true)
            //{
                //blocked
            //}
            //if (flag == false)
            {
                //flag = true;
                if (!secondChoiceResults.Contains(currentNode.representingStance.SequenceOfHolds))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("new addition");
                    secondChoiceResults.Add(currentNode.representingStance.SequenceOfHolds, currentNode.representingStance);
                }
                //flag = false;
                writingFlag = true;
            }
        }


    }
    else
    {
        int nextIndex = index + 1;
        goDownLinkType2(splittedString, nextIndex, (SuffixNode)currentNode.childHolds[splittedString[nextIndex]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if such thing happens i.e. two threads enter at once, wouldnt visual studio point it out as an exception?

Comment: Debugging parallelism issues is very difficult and threads waiting is not a problem as far as the debugger is concerned... maybe you're waiting for a really long asynchronous operation to complete.